# Tabularx vfill in column to fill rest of page

Tags: tabularx, vertical-spacing

I need to write my abstract in a table as my code example shows.
The cell with the actual abstract should be enlarged after the abstract text ends or filled with white space to make the table fill the rest of the page.
Is there a command for tabularx which functions like \vfill so the bottom cell is aligned with the bottom page margin? Thank you in advance!

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\spacing{1.5}

\newlength{\defaulttabcolsep}
\setlength{\defaulttabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Abstract}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X |}
    \hline
    Some information.\\\hline
    Some more information.\\\hline
    Abstract begins here.\\
    The height of this cell should be enlarged to make the table fill the rest of the page.\\\hline
    Some information on the bottom of the page.\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\setlength\tabcolsep{\defaulttabcolsep}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why use a one-row-one-column table?  If you must just use `\\[200pt]` before the final hline, just using whatever value doesn't give an overful message

Comment: @David Carlisle Aren't there 4 rows and one column? To add space manually would be just the last option. I'd like to have it automatically done by some command.

Comment: oh sorry 1 column, (still  a one column table isn't really a table either:-)  you could use  `\pagetotal` to estimate where you are on the page and add a suitable length in the argument

Comment: Since the content of the bottom cell, which should be exactly at the bottom of the page, can vary, I'm not able to figure out how I can calculate a length with `\pagetotal`.